Covariance stationarity for an AR(1) with squared terms?
I have a simple, but surprisingly mind-numbing, problem. I am familiar with determining stationarity for an AR(p) process: look at the roots from the characteristic equation. What if we had higher-order terms in our AR(p) process?
Suppose we have a time series and wish to estimate an AR(1) process using the linear and quadratic term:
$$y_t=\beta_0 +\beta_1 y_{t-1}+\beta_2 y_{t-1}^2 +\epsilon_t$$ For simplicity, let's assuming $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t],\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^2]<\infty$.
The question: How do you determine if the series is weakly stationary?

Hi Danny: I've never seen anything like that. I can't say that it's not possible to estimate it but it's definitely not an AR(1). You'd also most likely have a lot of problems with multi-collinearity if you tried to estimate it. Hopefully, someone else can say more ? It seems to me like you're thinking about an AR(1) from a regression perspective which is probably not the best way to think about it.

@christoph-hanck, thank you for editing my question. It is much more clear. I am pondering  your points below.

Danny: Based on what Christoph showed, I think estimating this would be difficult because of the eventual divergence, even if multicollinearity is not a problem.  Thanks Christoph for the detailed analysis.

@mlofton, why would multicollinearity be a problem here?

Hi Richard: Often, in time-series regressions, it's a problem. For example, suppose you have $y_t = \beta_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 X_{t-2}$. Then it's often differentiate  dis$\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ because the values of $X$ don't change very much from time to time. So, there's a lot of correlation between adjacent $X_t$ terms. In fact, this was the reason why the Koyck Distributed Lag was developed.

But, in this case, I'm not sure if it's worse or better because now the second coefficient has a value that is an actual function of the other value ? Is this worse, than an adjacent term being similar in value, I'm not sure. Rather than saying multi-collinearity, I should have said that ( taking the time subscripts out for a moment ) a functional form ( second order polynomial ) is being imposed as the relationship.

In thinking about it now, I don't know if imposing that functional form can cause multi-collinearity but it doesn't seem like something one would want to do without evidence, particularly in a time-series framework. My thinking is that now you're saying that, not only is it polynomial but it's a time  dependent polynomial !!!! That seems odd to me but I appreciate your point about not necessarily existence of multi-collinearity. You are most likely correct and I am most likely wrong.

Still, my intuition says that fitting something like that  would be problematic. Maybe I'm biased and it's due only to  my frustrating experiences with obtaining model estimates from  data. I still get tremors thinking about trying to construct estimates of models and eventually realizing that it would never work for whatever reason. I even get flashbacks :).

@mlofton, thanks for the explication. I see your points. I do not think multicollinearity is likely to be a problem here. There is no reason for $|\text{Corr}(y_{t-1},y_{t-1}^2)|$ to be close to 1, except perhaps for some special cases.

Right about it not being near 1.  I never thought of it that way.

I'm just curious, do you know if there are other conditions for a matrix to be not invertible besides that one. I've always had lots of problems with matrix inversions over the years and never really grocked it.

@mlofton, sorry, I do not have much experience with inverting nasty matrices, and I have not developed a deep understanding of the matter.

no problem richard. I just remember having lots of problems with estimation due to numerical issues. It may have been something as straightforward as one of the columns being close to a multiple of another. On the other hand, it may have been something else. Regardless, in this current model, multi-collinearity is not obvious. Thanks.

While I do not have a proof, I think that, sooner or later, such processes will become explosive. Consider
set.seed(1)
n <- 10000
y <- rep(0,n)
u <- rnorm(n)

for (i in 2:n){
  y[i] <- .1 + .1*y[i-1] + .2*y[i-1]^2 + u[i]
}
window <- 1300
plot(1:window, y[1:window], type="l")

cbind(u[1270:1300],y[1270:1300])

This process "looks" stationary for quite a while, essentially as long as $y_t$ takes values sufficiently close to zero so that $\beta_2y_{t}^2$ is also "small".
However, around $t\approx1300$ there is a large positive innovation $u_t$ at a point where the process $y_t$ was at fairly large values already. This implies that the squared value $y_t^2$ will take even larger values, pushing the next value $y_{t+1}$ even higher, with explosive values $y_{t+2},y_{t+3},...$ as a consequence. So my conjecture would be that this class of processes is not stable. (Clearly however, stability and stationarity are not the same thing, cf. Explosive AR(MA) processes are stationary?, so that my answer is maybe more like a lengthy comment.)
When $\beta_1<0$, such large values of $\beta_2y_{t}^2$ are to some extent counteracted, but experimentation suggests that, at some point, explosion still occurs.
Essentially, when $\beta_1y_t+\beta_2y_{t}^2$ jointly behave like $ay_t$ for $|a|>1$ in an explosive AR(1) model, the values will diverge.
In contrast, for a conventional AR(1), a coefficient less than one in absolute value will always ensure that, on average, the next value is in absolute value smaller than the current one, thus avoiding such explosive behavior.


A nitpick: maybe explosion instead of explosivity (...still occurs). Not entirely sure. Anyway, I wonder if/how standard tools for checking stationarity could be applied to this example.

Thanks. I was thinking about the standard tools first, too. However, being ultimately based on theory for linear difference equations, I am not sure if/how they are to work here. By https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_theorem, if the process is stationary, it would be possible to write it as such a causal linear process, but I do not see how. Recursive substitution in any case would lead to multiplicative terms, seemingly violating the Wold representation.

Thank you. That is how I was thinking, too.

Thank you for your comments. The next direction is to focus on stochastic nonlinear difference equations. Thanks everyone!

It kind of seems like you'd want to look at testivirta's material. Let me find his correct name and get back to you. He did ( and maybe still does )  a lot of non-linear time series stuff.

This gives his name correctly. I don't know anything about it but he's probably someone to start with. https://typeset.io/papers/modelling-nonlinear-economic-time-series-vydxvd2m8n

The name is Timo Teräsvirta :)

For those interested, I found some discussion on this problem: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2345901?sid=primo&seq=5
